# what exactly does the "context" mean? For soundPool.load int load(Context context, int resId, int priority)

Tags: android, soundpool

Recently I am trying to use SoundPool play some simple sound effect in my app

but unfortunately it doesn't work and app crash in AVD

what exactly does the "context" mean?

totally clueless

thanks in advance

Comment: post your code you tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any context allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

Normally you can use `this.YourClassName` as context.

Eg: `soundID = soundPool.load(this.MainActivity, R.raw.sound1, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

`Activity` is a subclass of `Context`, so you can just pass `this` withing an `Activity` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`Intent` is your **ears** regards to Android device. Your activity can talk to Android through `Intent` and listen on "any change" on your phone.

You have 4 options:

```
public int load (AssetFileDescriptor afd, int priority) 
public int load (String path, int priority) 
public int load (Context context, int resId, int priority) 
public int load (FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length, int priority)
```

No matter what method you use, need `Context` to "find out" resources on your Android.

If you going to use `AssetFileDescriptor` or `FileDescriptor` you need provide context to initiate them.